# how to fix this error "Cannot set property 't' of undefined" in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am new on react
I tried to execute this function in react

```
export default class App extends Component{
render(){
function SSS(t)
{
  this.t=t;
 return this;
}
console.log(SSS(1).t);
}return(
<h1>H</h1>
)}
}
```

but it still gives me that error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 't' of undefined
```

I read about "this" in MDN 
they mentioned the reason of this error is how to call the function
it works perfectly on js pure.
could you help me with that,please ?
thnx!

Comment: You're calling this inside an object/class what is `this` in here?

Comment: there is 3 context for this as they mention here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

`SSS` function call should assign `t` variable onto its execution context, e.g., if you call it in within window object, the variable can be accessed from there, 
`window.t // 1`. Provided you are in `'use strict'` mode., you will get
`TypeError: Cannot set property 't' of undefined`

If you want to bind custom context to `SSS`, you should either use `call/apply/bind`, examples:

```
SSS.call({}, 1)
SSS.apply({}, [1])
SSS.bind({})(1);
```

or **constructor** call:

```
new SSS(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You're using "this" in a function-in-function, "this" is not defined there.

What you want is put SSS(t) outside of render, as a class method.

Like this:

```
export default class App extends Component{
  SSS(t)
  {
    this.t=t;
    return this;
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.SSS(1).t);
    return(
      <h1>H</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, not that doing this.t = t is dangerous in React. You should probably use this.state.t and this.setState() instead. Check this for more info :

- [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)
- https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html